# Why not auto update list when used LiveData in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, koin

In my application I want use **Koin** , **Room** and **LiveData**.
I write below codes, but after add new item into room not auto update recyclerview list! 
Should close app and open again for show updated list !

**Dao codes :**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM $NOTE_TABLE")
fun getAllNote(): MutableList<NoteModel>
```

**Repository codes :**

```
class RoomRepository(private val dao: NoteDao) {

    suspend fun saveNote(note: NoteModel) = dao.saveNote(note)
    fun getAllNotes() = dao.getAllNote()

}
```

**ViewModel codes:**

```
class RoomViewModel(private val repository: RoomRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val notesList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<NoteModel>>()

    fun saveNote(note:NoteModel) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.saveNote(note)
    }

    fun loadAllNotes() = viewModelScope.launch {
        val list = repository.getAllNotes()
        if (list.isNotEmpty()) {
            notesList.postValue(list)
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity codes :**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityKoinRoomBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        //InitViews
        binding.apply {
            //Save
            btnSave.setOnClickListener {
                val title = titleEdt.text.toString()
                note.id = 0
                note.title = title
                viewModel.saveNote(note)
            }
            //Load notes
            viewModel.loadAllNotes()
            viewModel.notesList.observe(this@KoinRoomActivity) {
                noteAdapter.differ.submitList(it)

                notesList.apply {
                    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@KoinRoomActivity)
                    adapter = noteAdapter
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to update data immediately, you need to return `LiveData<T>` from the database itself. In your case, do something like that:

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM $NOTE_TABLE")
fun getAllNote(): LiveData<List<NoteModel>>
```

I also changed `MutableList` to `List`, because there is no need for mutability here.

You `ViewModel` can then be like this:

```kotlin
class RoomViewModel(private val repository: RoomRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val notesList = repository.getAllNotes()

    ...
}
```

and you can also remove function `loadAllNotes()` from it.

Comment: Thanks, after change codes show me error in `RoomViewModel` for `postValue`

Comment: I just added this part to the answer :)